# Easytether won't install

Tags: internet, easytether

I have a computer running Ubuntu 18.4 and I'm trying to install Easytether on the computer side but if I try to install the deb package I get an error message.

The computer has no internet service. I have seen posts from years ago about this but things have changed since then. The instructions that the easytether site provides are very vague and seem to be a little outdated.

I renamed the file tether.deb but I'll type the message I get.

## : sudo dpkg -i tether.deb

(Reading database ... 125613 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack tether.deb ...
Unpacking easytether (0.8.7-1) over (0.8.7-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of easytether:
easytether depends on resolvconf; however:
Package resolvconf is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package easytether (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigued
Errors were encountered while processing:
easytether

## :~/

That is the message I get. I downloaded resolvconf but I'm not sure how to go about installing that deb file. Untill I can get the internet connection going I have to do everything on my phone.

Comment: You need to show us the specific error message in order for us to assist you.  We can't help if we can't see the error message.

Comment: I must have really stumped everyone on this.